# Verify if user is able to SSH using password

Tags: ansible

I would like to test if a user is able to SSH using SSH password. That's all I would like to do. I tried with modules: local_action, wait_for but those didn't get me the results. The playbook result must simply tell me where a connection succeeded or failed when trying to SSH.

The requirement is to test which user account succeeds in making a SSH connection to remote servers. The user who would be running the ansible script has multiple accounts on these servers but SSH login will succeed with just the right one which the user doesn't know. The user accounts all have the same password.

The inventory file:

```
all:
  children:
    FXO-Test:
      hosts:        
        host1.abcd.com:
        host2.abcd.com:

      vars:
        ansible_user: user1
```

The Playbook:

```
---
  - hosts: "{{ targethosts }}"
    gather_facts: no
    tasks:
    - name: Test connection
      local_action: command ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=3 {{ inventory_hostname }}
      register: test_user
      ignore_errors: true
      changed_when: false
```

Invoked Using Command:

```
ansible-playbook checkLogin.yml -i ans_inventory_test --ask-pass --extra-vars "targethosts=FXO-Test"  | tee verify_user.log
```

Expected to see which SSH connections failed and which ones worked.

Based on Vladimir Botka response, I tweaked the playbook a bit further to pull hostnames from an inventory file.

My Updated Playbook 'verifySSHLogin.yml':

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    my_users:
      - user1
      - user2
    my_hosts: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'all') }}"
  tasks:
    - expect:
        command: "ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no {{ item.0 }}@{{ item.1 }}"
        timeout: 2
        responses:
          (.*)password(.*):
            - "password"      # Fit the password
            - "\x03"          # Ctrl-C
          (.*)\$(.*): "exit"  # Fit the prompt
      loop: "{{ my_users|product(my_hosts)|list }}"
      register: result
      ignore_errors: yes
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (item.rc  == 0)|ternary(item.invocation.module_args.command ~ ' [OK]',item.invocation.module_args.command ~ ' [KO]') }}"
      loop: "{{ result.results }}"
```

Which I now invoke using below command:

```
ansible-playbook verifySSHLogin.yml -i ans_inventory_test --extra-vars "targethosts=FXO-Test"  | tee verify_user.log
```

I can then do a grep against verify_user.log like this:

```
grep '\"msg\": \"ssh' verify_user.log
```

Which gives me below result which is what I was expecting:

```
"msg": "ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@host1.abc.corp.com [OK]"
"msg": "ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@host2.abc.corp.com [OK]"
"msg": "ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@host3.abc.corp.com [KO]"
"msg": "ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user2@host1.abc.corp.com [KO]"
"msg": "ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user2@host2.abc.corp.com [KO]"
"msg": "ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user2@host3.abc.corp.com [KO]"
```

Tweaked the playbook further to avoid hard-coding of SSH password. The final playbook looks like now:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    my_users:
      - user1
      - user2
    my_hosts: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'all') }}"
  tasks:
    - expect:
        command: "ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no {{ item.0 }}@{{ item.1 }}"
        timeout: 2
        responses:
          (.*)password(.*):
            - "{{ ansible_password }}"      # Fit the password
            - "\x03"          # Ctrl-C
          (.*)\$(.*): "exit"  # Fit the prompt
      loop: "{{ my_users|product(my_hosts)|list }}"
      register: result
      ignore_errors: yes
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (item.rc  == 0)|ternary(item.invocation.module_args.command ~ ' [OK]',item.invocation.module_args.command ~ ' [KO]') }}"
      loop: "{{ result.results }}"
```

The SSH password can be passed to ansible-playbook command like this:

```
ansible-playbook verifySSHLogin.yml -i ans_inventory_test -k --extra-vars "targethosts=FXO-Test"  | tee verify_user.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[expect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html#expect-executes-a-command-and-responds-to-prompts) module shall do the job. Given the
user1@test_01 is able to log in, the play below

```yaml
    - hosts: localhost

      vars:

        my_users:
          - user1
          - user2
        my_hosts:
          - test_01
          - test_02

      tasks:

        - expect:
            command: "ssh {{ item.0 }}@{{ item.1 }}"
            timeout: 2
            responses:
              (.*)password(.*):
                - "password"      # Fit the password
                - "\x03"          # Ctrl-C
              (.*)\$(.*): "exit"  # Fit the prompt
          with_nested:
            - "{{ my_users }}"
            - "{{ my_hosts }}"
          register: result
          ignore_errors: yes
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ (item.rc  == 0)|ternary(item.invocation.module_args.command ~ ' [OK]',
                                             item.invocation.module_args.command ~ ' [KO]') }}"
          loop: "{{ result.results }}"
```

gives (grep msg):

```yaml
  msg: ssh user1@test_01 [OK]
  msg: ssh user1@test_02 [KO]
  msg: ssh user2@test_01 [KO]
  msg: ssh user2@test_02 [KO]
```

---

**update**

Update the expected regex

```py
(.*)[P|p]assword(.*)
```

and put passwords into a dictionary `my_passwd` (encrypt in production)

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_users:
      - alice
      - bob
    my_hosts:
      - test_11
      - test_13
    my_passwd:
      test_11:
        alice: alice
        bob: bob
      test_13:
        alice: alice
        bob: bob

  tasks:

    - expect:
        command: "ssh {{ item.0 }}@{{ item.1 }}"
        timeout: 5
        responses:
          (.*)[P|p]assword(.*):
            - "{{ my_passwd[item.1][item.0] }}"  # Fit the password
            - "\x03"                             # Ctrl-C
          (.*)\$(.*): "exit"                     # Fit the prompt
      with_nested:
        - "{{ my_users }}"
        - "{{ my_hosts }}"
      register: result
      ignore_errors: true

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (item.rc  == 0)|ternary(item.invocation.module_args.command ~ ' [OK]',
                                         item.invocation.module_args.command ~ ' [KO]') }}"
      loop: "{{ result.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.cmd }}"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :-). I tweaked it a bit so that hostnames are picked from inventory file.